# RegEx em JavaScript e C# para validação de texto

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

Em uma aplicação `Asp.Net WebForms`, tenho um `TextBox` que necessito validar se o mesmo contém algum trecho onde existam `<` seguido por qualquer caractere exceto espaço em branco.

Por exemplo:

`Nesse texto pode existir < com espaço.
Mas não pode <. <+ <? </ <\ <A <0 <*`

Nesse caso, o RegEx deve encontrar oito resultados = `<.`, `<+`, `<?`, `</`, `<\`, `<A`, `<0` e `<*` e não identificar `<` *(que contém o espaço)*.
*Onde `A` representa qualquer caractere alfanumérico e `0` qualquer número.*

Esse RegEx será utilizado no evento `onchange()` da página HTML via JavaScript e no `TextChanged()` no Asp.Net.

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: É pra detectar html?

Comment: É bem similar, mas a finalidade não é exatamente essa...
Encontrei validações para HTML, mas não consegui adaptar para a utilização que preciso...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se compreendi muito bem, veja se este exemplo ajuda.

```html
<input type="text" id="input_teste" name="input_teste"/>
<input type="submit" value="Testar" onclick="valida_teste()"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
function valida_teste()
{ var filter_test = /< /g;
  if(!filter_test.test(input_teste.value))
  {   alert("O valor : " + input_teste.value + "é incorreto");
  }else
  {   alert("O valor : " + input_teste.value + "é correto");
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Perfeito! É isso mesmo.
*Obrigado _MagicHat_.*

Comment: Blz...Então entendi certo, heheh